# Raise a ValueError when convert one column from vertical to horizontal in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
  city          id     date  price
0   sh  3910060461  2008-04  19459
1   sh  1210000631  2008-05  16727
2   bj  1210000770  2008-05  12960
3   bj  1210000829  2008-05  14445
4   bj  1210001004  2008-05  16213
```

How could I convert `date` columns horizontally and map `price` into it based on `city` and `id`?

The expected result is like this:

```
  city          id  2008-04  2008-05
0   sh  3910060461  19459.0      NaN
1   sh  1210000631      NaN  16727.0
2   bj  1210000770      NaN  12960.0
3   bj  1210000829      NaN  14445.0
4   bj  1210001004      NaN  16213.0
```

I try `df.pivot_table(columns = 'date', index=['city', 'id'], values = 'price', fill_value ='').reset_index()`, but it raises an error:

```
ValueError: a CategoricalDtype must be passed to perform an update, got CategoricalDtype(categories=[0], ordered=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by all three columns of interest, then convert the dates index level to column names with `unstack`. Not a perfect solution, but it works.

```
transformed = df.groupby(['city','id','date']).first().unstack().reset_index()
#     city          id    price         
#date                   2008-04  2008-05
#0      bj  1210000770      NaN  12960.0
#1      bj  1210000829      NaN  14445.0
#2      bj  1210001004      NaN  16213.0
#3      sh  1210000631      NaN  16727.0
#4      sh  3910060461  19459.0      NaN
```

You can flatten the column names if you want:

```
transformed.columns = [(l1 or l0) for l0,l1 in transformed]
#  city          id  2008-04  2008-05
#0   bj  1210000770      NaN  12960.0
#1   bj  1210000829      NaN  14445.0
#2   bj  1210001004      NaN  16213.0
#3   sh  1210000631      NaN  16727.0
#4   sh  3910060461  19459.0      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Could we have a result exact as in the OP, I try to save your result with `data.to_excel("./test.xlsx")`, I get `AttributeError: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'common'`

Comment: Your problem is caused by something else. There is nothing `common` in my answer.

Comment: I added a fragment for flattening the column names.

Answer (score 1):

`Groupby` three columns except `Price`.Hold `Price` in list and `unstack()` date. Drop `level=0` on columns.

```
print(df.groupby(['city', 'id', 'date'])['price'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist())).unstack('date').droplevel(0, axis=1))
                            
date               2008-04  2008-05
city id                            
bj   1210000770 0      NaN  12960.0
     1210000829 0      NaN  14445.0
     1210001004 0      NaN  16213.0
sh   1210000631 0      NaN  16727.0
     3910060461 0  19459.0      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution seems quite slow, also in `city` column, there are `NaN`s.

Comment: I had @DYZ 's solution but he got it faster. My solution would be slower. Just provide an alternative. City is not null, just resetting index would cascade values. For instance print(df.groupby(['city', 'id', 'date'])['price'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist())).unstack('date').reset_index().drop(columns=['level_2']))

Comment: `.apply` is _very_ slow.

Comment: OK thank you anyway. It's weird the solution in my question previously works with a similar dataset, but now, it raise an error. Any ideas regarding that?

Comment: Possibly, the problem you have is caused by something else. Cant tell why it worked then and cant work now.